# CASSANDRA: Unable to open /var/lib/cassandra/hints

Tags: cassandra, directory, cassandra-3.0, hints

I'm trying to setup cassandra 3.11.6.1 (and tried with 3.11.4.1) but failed to make it works. In the yaml configuration I set directories values for commitlog, hints, data and saved_cache to another root dir but in the logs it seems that cassandra doesn't take care of it as it tries to open directories in the default conf root dir:

```
WARN  [HintsWriteExecutor:1] 2020-05-06 11:30:34,864 NativeLibrary.java:306 - open(/var/lib/cassandra/hints, O_RDONLY) failed, errno (2).
ERROR [HintsWriteExecutor:1] 2020-05-06 11:30:34,864 HintsCatalog.java:167 - Unable to open directory /var/lib/cassandra/hints
```

The group/owner is correctly set and chmod is 0777 to avoid any user rights problems.
The last thing I've tried is to create a symlink /var/lib/cassandra pointing to my datastore directory but it doesn't change anything.

Is it possible to use antoher directory configuration but default one?
Is someone have faced this problem and solved it? (and how, please)

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that cassandra reads /etc/cassandra/default.conf/cassandra.yaml even if you create your own cassandra.yaml in /etc/cassandra